# How to create a glass effect on a circle?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've made a circle for display the status of a connection for my DB, it's working nice but I want to make it look like a bulb with glass effects.

```
<Canvas Visibility="Visible" x:Name="connection_red" Grid.Column="1">
                    <Ellipse
                      Fill="Red"
                      Height="13"
                      Width="13"
                      Margin="0,7,80,0"
                      StrokeThickness="1"
                      Stroke="White"/>
                </Canvas>
```

I have visited many online tutorials, but they use too much code and I do not want to use 50 lines of code to achieve this effect. Someone knows how to do to get the effect glass bulb in a few lines of code? You can show me the way?

This is the actual preview:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either specify the opacity seperately...

```
<Ellipse  Fill="#FF0000" Opacity="0.25"
              Height="130"
              Width="130"
              Margin="0,7,80,0"
              StrokeThickness="1"
              Stroke="White" />
```

...or use a SolidColorBrush...

```
<Canvas Visibility="Visible" x:Name="connection_red" Grid.Column="1">
    <Ellipse  Height="130"
              Width="130"
              Margin="0,7,80,0"
              StrokeThickness="1"
              Stroke="White">
        <Ellipse.Fill>
            <SolidColorBrush>
                <SolidColorBrush.Color>
                    <Color A="25" R="255" G="0" B="0" />
                </SolidColorBrush.Color>
            </SolidColorBrush>
        </Ellipse.Fill>
    </Ellipse>
```

Would be good though if you could clarify exactly what type of effect you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Canvas Visibility="Visible" x:Name="connection_red" Grid.Column="1">
                <Ellipse
                  Fill="#7FFF0000"
                  Height="13"
                  Width="13"
                  Margin="0,7,80,0"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stroke="White"/>
            </Canvas>
```

Comment: Fill=Color A="255" R="250" G="200" B="150" missing comma for attribute value

Comment: Fill=Color A="255" R="250" G="200" B="150" this not working.